# How to attach disks in azure vm using Terraform code

Tags: terraform

I am trying to create multiple vms and managed disk to associate after creation. I could see the disks are created and getting associated only for the first VM in the list. I am not sure how to assign the right index number in the below code.

I believe Virtual_Machine_id is creating this issue, has any one came across the similar, please advice.

````
resource “azurerm_managed_disk” “app_managed_disk” {

  count = “${length(var.data_disk_names)}”

  name = “ var.apphostname−{var.data_disk_names[count.index %length(var.data_disk_names)]}”

  location = azurerm_resource_group.poc_rg.location

  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.poc_rg.name

  storage_account_type = var.app_disk_type

  create_option = “Empty”

  disk_size_gb = “${var.data_disk_sizes[count.index % length(var.data_disk_sizes)]}”

}

resource “azurerm_virtual_machine_data_disk_attachment” “app_disk_attach” {

  count = “${length(var.data_disk_names)}”

  vm_count = length(var.vm_app_name)

  managed_disk_id = “${azurerm_managed_disk.app_managed_disk[count.index % length(azurerm_managed_disk.app_managed_disk)].id}”

  virtual_machine_id = azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.app-vm-pas[0].id

  lun = “${count.index + 1}”

  caching = “ReadWrite”

}

```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through all the VMs and corresponding virtual disks, Assumption here would be you want to create multiple similarly attached disks to a set of similar virtual machines

From your code above you were on the right path but you seem to only be referencing the first VM when mounting, this might serve you better:

```
variable "cnt" {
  default     = 1
  description = "instances to be created"
}
variable "managed_disks" {
  type = list(map(string))
  default = []
}
#cnt=2
#managed_disks = [{
#    storage_account_type : "Premium_LRS"
#    disk_size_gb : "256"
#  }]
resource "azurerm_managed_disk" "default" {
  count = length(var.managed_disks)>0?(length(var.managed_disks)*var.cnt):0
  name                 = "${var.name}-md-${count.index%var.cnt}-${count.index%length(var.managed_disks)}"
  location             = var.location
  resource_group_name  = var.resource_group
  storage_account_type = coalesce(var.managed_disks[count.index%length(var.managed_disks)].storage_account_type,"StandardSSD_LRS")
  create_option        = "Empty"
  disk_size_gb         = coalesce(var.managed_disks[count.index%length(var.managed_disks)].disk_size_gb,"64")

  tags = merge(
    var.tags,
    {
    }
  )
}
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_data_disk_attachment" "default" {
  count = length(var.managed_disks)>0?(length(var.managed_disks)*var.cnt):0
  managed_disk_id    = azurerm_managed_disk.default[count.index].id
  virtual_machine_id = azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.default[count.index%var.cnt].id
  lun                = 1+count.index
  caching            = "ReadWrite"

}
```

With this, you should be able to bring up a set of VMs with corresponding similarly-defined managed disks for each of them.